# R: Selecting a subset of a sqlite database based on a character vector

Tags: r, sqlite

I am trying to extract part of my database using a character vector. To explain, I have used the mtcars data as below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)
library(RSQLite)

df <- cbind(rownames(mtcars),mtcars)
colnames(df)[1] <- "CarName"
CarsToFind <- c("Valiant", "Merc 280", "Lotus Europa", "Volvo 142E")
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = 'mtcars_db.sqlite3')
dbWriteTable(conn = db, name = 'mtcars_table', value = df, row.names = TRUE, header = TRUE)
```

I could find the section of the data frame that I am interested in using:

```
mini_df <- df[df$CarName %in% CarsToFind,]
```

but my real data is quite large and I would rather not extract the whole thing into a data frame. I am looking for something similar to :

```
sqldf("SELECT * FROM mtcars_table WHERE CarName IN CarsToFind")
```

but this gives me the error: "no such table: CarsToFind". I don't want to create the table 'CarsToFind' in the SQL databank, because I have many different queries that I want to perform on a once off basis. Is it possible to query the SQL using such a character vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query you actually want to execute on SQLite should look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mtcars
WHERE CarName IN ('Valiant', 'Merc 280', 'Lotus Europa', 'Volvo 142E')
```

So all you need to do is build this string in R:

```
CarsToFind <- c("Valiant", "Merc 280", "Lotus Europa", "Volvo 142E")
CarsToFind <- paste0("'", CarsToFind, "'", collapse=", ")
whereIn <- paste0("(", CarsToFind, ")")

query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE CarName IN ", whereIn)             
sqldf(query)
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the error message:
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) :  unrecognized token: "280â€™"
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you verify that `query` in fact has the correct query?

Comment: Yep, thanks, that was the problem. sQuote inserts ’ (curly quote symbol) whereas I needed ' (straight quote symbol). I just exchanged all the curly quotes for straight quotes with gsub and now it works perfectly. Thankyou!

Comment: @nm200 I updated my answer to just use `paste0()` to add single quotes to the `WHERE IN` terms.  I tested locally, and it appears to be generating the correct query now.

Comment: much more elegant than my solution. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of creating a character vector, create a `dataframe` with only one column? This would work:

```
CarsToFind <- data.frame(lookup=c("Valiant", "Merc 280", "Lotus Europa", "Volvo 142E"))

sqldf("SELECT * FROM df WHERE CarName IN CarsToFind")
```

Also, this way you don't have to change/add anything on the `SQL` side, you can still keep everything on the `R` side.

Comment: Awesome - so easy! Thanks Mike.

Comment: Sorry, answered too quickly... This still querries the dataframe, rather than the sql. When I change the df to mtcars (the name of the sql), I get the same error message 'no such table: CarsToFind'

Comment: Hm, can you post a reproducible error? In your original query, you refer to mtcars, but in mtcars there is not "CarName" variable